# Dash Callback does not update graph

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash

I'm reading in a csv file and I have a datepicker where the end user can choose start and end dates. Then a Bar chart is created below the date picker. I wrote the code below, and the date picker seems to work fine. The Bar chart is created but displays no data.

Can someone tell me why the callback isn't displaying the data?

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import pandas_datareader.data as web # requires v0.6.0 or later
from datetime import datetime

# Launch the application:
app = dash.Dash()

# Create a DataFrame from the .csv file:
#df = pd.read_csv('../data/OldFaithful.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('Data/DataFile.csv', delimiter=',', encoding="utf-8-sig")


# Create a Dash layout that contains a Graph component:
app.layout = html.Div([

html.Div([
    html.H3('Select start and end dates:'),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my_date_picker',
        min_date_allowed=datetime(2010, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=datetime.today(),
        start_date=datetime(2018, 1, 1), #datetime.today(),
        end_date=datetime(2018, 1, 10) #datetime.today()
    )
], style={'display':'inline-block'}),
dcc.Graph( id='data_numbers')
])

@app.callback(
    Output('data_numbers', 'figure'),
    [Input('my_date_picker', 'start_date'),
    Input('my_date_picker', 'end_date')])
def update_figure(start_date, end_date):
    start = datetime.start_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    end = datetime.end_date.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
    df['Counter'] = 1
    df1 = df #df[(df['Date Occurred'] > start_date) & (df['Date Occurred'] < end_date)]
    df2 = df1.groupby(['ColumnName' ]).agg({      # find the sum of the durations for each group
                                         'Counter': "count" # find the number of network type entries
                                         })    # get the first date per group
    df3 = df2.unstack
    df4 = df2.reset_index(level=[0,0])
    return {'data':[go.Bar(x=df4['ColumnName'],
                              y=df4['Counter'],
                              mode='markers',
                              marker={'size':15,
                                      'opacity':0.5,
                                      'line':{'width':0.5,'color':'green'}})
                              ],
                              'layout':go.Layout(title='My Bar Graph',
                              xaxis = {'title':'X Column'},
                              yaxis = {'title':'Y Column'},
                              hovermode='closest'),}




# Add the server clause:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't attach a CSV file so I use random data.

```
from datetime import datetime
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import pandas as pd

idx = pd.date_range(datetime(2018, 1, 1, 0), datetime(2018, 2, 1, 0), freq='H')
df = pd.Series(index=idx, data=pd.np.random.rand(1, idx.size)[0])

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div(children=[
    html.H1(children='Hello Dash'),
    dcc.DatePickerRange(
        id='my_date_picker',
        min_date_allowed=datetime(2018, 1, 1),
        max_date_allowed=datetime(2018, 2, 1),
        start_date=datetime(2018, 1, 1),
        end_date=datetime(2018, 1, 10)
    ),
    dcc.Graph(id='data_numbers')
])


@app.callback(
    Output('data_numbers', 'figure'),
    [Input('my_date_picker', 'start_date'), Input('my_date_picker', 'end_date')]
)
def update_figure(start_date, end_date):
    idx_up = df.index[(df.index >= datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) & (df.index <= datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y-%m-%d'))]
    df_up = df[idx_up].groupby([idx_up.year, idx_up.month, idx_up.day]).mean()
    trace = go.Bar(
        x=pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='D'),
        y=df_up.values
    )
    return {
        'data': [trace],
        'layout': go.Layout(
            title='My Bar Graph',
            xaxis=go.layout.XAxis(range=[start_date, end_date]),
            hovermode='closest'
        )
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for doing this. I noticed my code is generating an error message after I change the dates -